# css padding-left not working in chrome and firefox

Tags: html, css

I have below css within a div

```
<div>
<span>
<ul></ul>
</span>
</div>

#SPAN {
    PADDING-RIGHT: 0px; PADDING-LEFT : 14px; FONT-SIZE: 11px; FONT-FAMILY:Tahoma; PADDING-BOTTOM: 0px; WIDTH: 100%; PADDING-TOP: 15px; HEIGHT: 100%
}



#UL {
PADDING-RIGHT: 0px; PADDING-LEFT: 0px; PADDING-BOTTOM: 0px; MARGIN: 0px; 
}
```

Here padding-left within the span tag does not work in chrome and firefox. i have tried some workaround like text-indent: 14px and padding: 0 0 0 14px and it does not seem to work. Any help would be appreciated.Thanks in advance.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Answer my own question

instead of `PADDING-LEFT : 14px used MARGIN-LEFT: 14px`. This is recognized by firefox.

Comment: Yeah, this is a great answer, and it works for Chrome too :)

Answer (score 4):

wrap the style into a `<style></style>` block in the `head` section and remove the `#` from your selectors. The hash symbol needs to identify elements by `id` attribute, and your elements have none.

As a side note your markup is **not** valid, since you can't wrap an unordered list into a span element

Answer (score -3):

span is inline element and add display:inline-block to have block styles 

    #SPAN {
        PADDING-RIGHT: 0px; PADDING-LEFT : 14px; FONT-SIZE: 11px; FONT-FAMILY:Tahoma; PADDING-BOTTOM: 0px; WIDTH: 100%; PADDING-TOP: 15px; HEIGHT: 100%; display:inline-block;
    }

Comment: This option provided the required padding but increased the height of the div

Comment: @cxyz: Why'd you accept it then? Do you not care about the height increase?